# Symfony forms - partial object update

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Given a typical Doctrine entity used to manage say user accounts, suppose I want to provide registered users with a form which consists solely of a field used to modify their professional bio. This means *only* the description would be passed back to the `update` action:

```
public function updateAction(Project $project, Request $request)
{
  $user = SOME_RETRIEVED_USER_OBJECT;
  $form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);
  $form->bindRequest($request);
  ...
}
```

However, after executing `bindRequest`, all of the `$user` attribute values *except* for the bio are empty. Surely there is some way to perform a partial object update in Symfony?

Answer (score 4):

Fields at the form define what entity property will be updated. The easiest way is to create a separate form type with one field that needs to be updated and use

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserFormOneField(), $user);
```

Also you need to make sure that you select correct validation group for this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare your form to the POSTed values received and remove the ones that do not exist. You can add this function to your controller :

```
private function updateFormAccordingToRequest($form){
  $form_fields = array();
  foreach($form->getChildren() as $c) $form_fields[] = $c->getName();
  $post_fields = array_keys($this->getRequest()->request->get($form->getName()));
  $fields_to_remove = array_diff($form_fields, $post_fields);
  foreach($fields_to_remove as $f) $form->remove($f);
  return $form;
}
```

.. and then update your forms whenever you want to do partial updates :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserForm(), $user);
$form = $this->updateFormAccordingToRequest($form);
$form->bindRequest($request);
```